# In vscode how do you tell if or where a document provided by a TextDocumentContentProvider is shown

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am working on an extension in vscode that uses a `TextDocumentContentProvider` to provide users with feedback on the effects of changes they make to the file they are editing.

A common use case is for the user to drag the virtual document to a separate pane so they get a side by side view of the live document and the virtual document.

To display the virtual document, I need to call `showTextDocument()`, however this opens it in the current pane, giving two copies of the same document, and also makes it the current tab, hiding the document the user is working on.

I do not seem to get open or close events for virtual docs - which would mean I could just not call `showTextDocument()`, and I cannot find any API that allows me to find out or set which pane a document is open in.

Answer (score 0):

WebViews are a special document type. You neither can enumerate open tabs for them nor can you influence the exact tab position, except for the view column. OK, the same about the tab position can be said for normal text documents.

Comment: I'm not using a WebView, just displaying text in a read-only document via the TextDocumentContentProvider API. However, a WebView does have a dispose() method, so I could see when it is closed by the user and re-show if necessary, so perhaps I should be using one.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood then (took the "virtual document" metapher too far). So, you mean you don't get `workspace.onDidOpenTextDocument` and related events?

Comment: No, there don't appear to be any open/close events for the virtual docs. I need to get this done today, so even though it's a bit heavyweight, I'll switch to the WebView for now. Cheers.